# Does WordPress Change the .htaccess File When Updating?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, updates

I've just implemented a new WP website, replacing an older hardcoded HTML site. I will be adding 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` file to point the old URIs to the new WP Permalinks.

My questions is, as WP generates the `.htaccess` file initially (at least on my install it did) will WP overrite the `.htaccess` file when I update WP in the future?

Further to the above, is there any time, including the update as mentioned above, that WP may overwrite this file and if so is there a way to prevent that?

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find a straight answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Generally speaking WordPress will update the .htaccess file any time you change the permalink structure. Many plugins will also update/modify the file as needed.

But the default structure of the .htaccess file allows you to lay it out in such a way that WordPress will not overwrite your custom entries.

WordPress will overwrite the entries between '# BEGIN WordPress' and '# END WordPress'. While most plugins will create their own begin and end tags and only update within those tags.

Simply put your custom entries outside of any custom tags/comments and they *SHOULD* be preserved when WP updates the file.

Comment: I have to lines in my .htaccess which make sure my site is always served over https:
`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$`
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`
How can I put these outside? Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 5):

No, normally only if you change the permalink structure. Often a plugin is the problem. But you can use an FTP tool, or SSH, to change the access rights of the .htaccess file to something like 644, so that scripts don't change the data.