# Couple questions about .htaccess, login page, updates

Tags: wp-admin, login, htaccess, security, updates

I want to secure my login page, but with this problem came some newbie questions too, I guess.

Firstly, if I change some of the `.htaccess` files, how properly should I do this in order not to make problems for my self in the future updates of WP core? For example, if I'll download and modify this type of file, what would happen if the WP core would need to update this file?

Another question is about replacing the address of the login page, so only I would know it. Is this even possible? I know there some tools for hackers that they run and get the whole tree of folders and files on the server... If this is not true, could you then please tell me and I would be extremely grateful, how to remove to other location and rename my wp-admin folder and/or login page for admin, but please, without plugins?

Thanks in advance, 
Mia.

Answer (score 0):

For the .htaccess-question, Stephen has a nice answer to that [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71213/does-wordpress-change-the-htaccess-file-when-updating):

> WordPress will overwrite the entries between '# BEGIN WordPress' and '# END WordPress'. While most plugins will create their own begin and end tags and only update within those tags.
>
> Simply put your custom entries outside of any custom tags/comments and
>   they SHOULD be preserved when WP updates the file.

You can change the address of the admin login using either an existing plugin (Google "change wordpress login url"), or by modifying the .htaccess-file. See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6402/is-there-any-way-to-rename-or-hide-wp-login-php) for more info.